# How to view CAD Drawing file in WebMap application

Tags: asp.net, open-source, autocad-plugin, autodesk-viewer

Dears,

I am in need of any DLL or API (free / very low cost) to view the Autocad drawing file through my web-map application which was developed by using C#.Net and ArcGIS Javascript API 3.16. I got an opensource tool, that is Sharecad.org's iframe tool. But it requires the internet and public IP in the server to read our .dwg file. But my environment and requirements are viewing the dwg files without installing Autocad in intranet systems which are connected in LAN Network and read only option is enough with basic zoom in, zoom out and pan options.

Seeking your suggestion and solution and it is more helpful to me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell whether this will meet your requirements or not, but Autodesk uses their forge platform for viewing. https://developer.autodesk.com/